# Node script ReferenceError: fs is not defined error in test script

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying out node to run a simple js script to read a file,
following is the content of my script:

```
"use strict"
fs = require('fs');
var args = process.argv.slice(2);
fs.readFile(args, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
        }
    console.log("Reading from file " + args);
    console.log(data);
});
```

when I try to run this using the following command:
node myTestFile.js testFile

I get this error:

```
fs = require('fs');
   ^
ReferenceError: fs is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous>     (/<Path to file>/myTestFile.js:2:4)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:393:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:508:3
```

Isn't fs in node like a library like stdio in c ?

Do we have to explicitly define the library path somewhere in node ?

How can I get the above example to work ?

Comment: You're trying to assign to a variable you haven't declared: `fs`. Add `var` (or `let` or `const`) in front of it. You can get away with doing that in loose mode (it creates an [implicit global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), which is a Bad Thing™), but not in strict mode, and you really don't *want* to get away with that...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The problem is not `require('fs')`, but the left side; you'd get the same error with

```
fs = 42;
```

That's because there is no variable fs defined. Define it with `const`, `let`, or `var`, like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

Comment: Typo-style errors don't need answers, just comments and close-as-no-repro-votes.

Comment: It fix the close reason: *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."*

Comment: Sorry, as a non-native speaker, i must apologize for not understanding what `It fix the close reason` means. Can you elaborate? I believe to be well-aware of the close reason you cite. While the change is indeed only six characters, the semantic understanding of *why* these six characters is important.

Comment: It's not your fault, I mistyped: "It *fits* the close reason." I disagree about the semantics, the OP clearly knows they need to declare variables, and just forgot to in this case. Typo. Comment, vote-to-close, and move on. :-) (Speaking of moving on, dinner time here.)

Comment: I would like to clarify here that, even though I was aware that it is a bad practice to not use var, const etc to declare the variables and missed writing that originally. I was not aware that "use strict" makes it illegal to use variables without explicit declaration :)

Comment: To me, this Q/A was important. I am a total beginner at js and without this, I would not even have found out that `fs` is just "a library like stdio in c". I thought it was an orphaned random variable in a broken code. Now I got an error fixed in an SSL API to PostgreSQL without knowing js. :) Therefore, I am glad that it got reopened.

Answer (score 5):

```js
// Define the `fs` at the beginning of the script
const fs = require('fs');
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the log

```
ReferenceError: fs is not defined
```

You have a ReferenceError you can define the JS

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

or

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

and declare the fs before using it.

const or var depend on the javascript syntax you are using to build your application