# error shows as "fs is not defined"

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I want to dump database records into a specified location. How can I do it?
I have tried from this link https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-replication-stream
But I get error as **fs is not defined**
here is the code

```
var db=new PouchDB('company_details');
function dumpdata(){
  var ws = fs.createWriteStream('file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/sevenadmin/db/output.txt');

  db.dump(ws).then(function (res) {
    //res should be {ok: true}
 }); 
}
```

what is fs here. I dint get it. How can i resolve it.
I use pouchdb and javascript. when I submit the form the data saved in indexeddb which is located in browser itself. Now I want to make it saved in specified location. any way?

Comment: You have to define `fs`; it's probably supposed to be the `FileSystem` subsystem that you'll need to `require`.

Comment: how can I define.. can u show bcoz I have tried many way.

Comment: fs is the FileSystem and you can't use it in the browser.

Comment: some times it asked require is not defined

Comment: What have you tried exactly? And where are you trying to run this code — in the browser or in Node.js?

Comment: in the browser.

Comment: You're probably going to need to use Browserify or something; that sample code you're trying was intended for Node.js programs.

Comment: ok I have installed nodejs in my laptop. Now can I run that? if yes can you please tel me how..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node script ReferenceError: fs is not defined error in test script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43171652/node-script-referenceerror-fs-is-not-defined-error-in-test-script)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define fs at the top.

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

Comment: now it asks require is not defined after defining fs

Comment: @Carlos Take a look at [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org) or alternatively [Bowserify](http://browserify.org)